# Can not logout from my PHP page but I log out from facebook account using SDK

Tags: php, facebook

From my external PHP page, the first time I used the application, I have logged in and allow the application to access my data. When this was completed the "logout" link in my page is appeared.

However, when I logout from my PHP page, it logs me out from my FB account but in PHP page I am logged in.
 How can I logout from my page? I have read that if you log out from your application there is another access_token generated. Is that correct?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logout problem is because of a recent Facebook API change – ‘offline_access Permission Removal’.

Disable the ‘Deprecate offline access’ setting from Edit App > Advanced > Migrations tab

You can read more about it at: http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Answer (score 0):

You code is missing the php destroy session.  Be sure to check both cookies (Facebook's and your webserver's) and make sure they're removed.

Comment: Thank you for this. Can you point me how to destroy the facebook cookie? I have destroyed the webserver's session

Comment: Please search StackOverflow.  I've seen this discussed in depth before.